# switching a job (pid) from running as root to just running as the current user

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, sync, bittorrent

I recently installed BitTorrent Sync version 2.0. It's purdy awesome! I've made a terrible error though. During the install process I ran `sudo ./btsync` instead of just `./btsync`. I'm pretty sure that's the reason all the files that get synced have root permissions.

Is there anyway to fix this? Or do I have to uninstall and start over?

I'm running 14.04 with Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

`su - yourusername ./btsync` should fix it. Just make sure the ./btsync has the right permissions for you to run it.

Comment: Weird, I get `-su: ./btsync: No such file or directory
Sessions still open, not unmounting`

Comment: Right. Try killing the process and running it again (`su - yourusername ./btsync`)

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: And if I kill the process and run ./btsync on it's own I get a permission denied error.

Comment: Wait, would this give sudo permission to all my actions? That's not smart.

Comment: Check this out. http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/16526-feedback-btsync-on-linux/ Apparently, running it with root permissions is the right way to do it.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't help at all. They don't say what to do about it creating files with only root permission.